# Getting error while connecting to virtual machine

Tags: linux, linuxthreads

key_exchange_identification: Connection closed by Remote host

trying to ssh from local host but suddenly it get lost in between
and after some time asking to re install again the OS

Answer (score 0):

[I hope this information can help you](https://askubuntu.com/q/1413264)

I run into a similar case with a small computer I have in my desk. What I did to debug the issue was to run sshd -t, which runs the sshd daemon in debug mode. This command reported that the permissions of my keys were invalid. All I had to do then was to go in the folder where the keys are stored and issue chmod 0600 <your_ssh_keys>. Maybe the action you run generated things with the wrong permissions too

This answer is from another source.